# MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: outlook.office365.com, 587;

Tags: java, email, smtp

I have created a simple java project, using Jakarta mail. On my work computer the app works fine, but when I run it on a Windows Server. I get an error.

I have tested different settings like turn on/off; tls and ssl, and also tried different ports like 25 and 465. I looked around the internet but could not find an answer.

Please need help, I've been stuck on this for over a week now.

```
private static void jakarta() 
    {
            // Set Email Service Properties
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host); // "outlook.office365.com"
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port); // 587
            properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);

try {
    // Init Message
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("[INFO] - Send Email successfully");

} catch (MessagingException e) {
    System.out.println("[BUG] - MessagingException, while building Email");
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("[BUG] - Unknown exception, building Email with attachment");
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

> [INFO] - Run Jakarta Mail DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 2.0.1 DEBUG:
> successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
> DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class
> Name:
> {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle],
> com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle],
> com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle],
> com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
> DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol:
> {imap=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle],
> pop3=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], imaps=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle],
> smtps=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle],
> pop3s=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
> DEBUG: successfully loaded resource:
> /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map DEBUG: getProvider() returning
> jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
> DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication DEBUG SMTP:
> protocolConnect returning false, host=outlook.office365.com,
> user=Lucas-admin, password= DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth
> true DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com",
> port 587, isSSL false [BUG] - MessagingException, while building Email
> com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
> port: outlook.office365.com, 587; timeout -1;   nested exception is:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722)
> at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
> at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
> at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
> at jakarta.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
> at jakarta.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
> at com.example.App.jakarta(App.java:57)
> at com.example.App.main(App.java:74) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
> at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
> at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:335)
> at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:214)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
> ... 8 more